# How can I keep screen session alive after LightDM restart?

Tags: 20.04, lightdm, tty, gnu-screen, xfce4-terminal

When I start a screen session from terminal emulator (PTS), it vanishes after I restart LightDM (`sudo service lightdm restart`).  However sessions started from TTY are preserved.

How can I keep screen sessions started from terminal emulator?